# Quit function is not working in pygame

Tags: python-3.x

I want the system to exit when I click the "x" on the window of pygame. I want to be able to call the `quit_game` function whenever I need to. So if the user does quit, it actually quits. I have tried `sys exit` and `pygame.quit()`, but I haven't been able to successfully implement those. Right now I just have the quit function built into the intro screen. I am using python 3.4.3. Here is the code.

```
import math
import random
import time
import pygame
import sys
import glob
pygame.init()
move=0
FPS=60
blue=(0,0,255)
white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,155,0)
display_width=800
display_height=600
gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Stacker')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
speed=2
smallfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(display_width/32))
mediumfont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(display_width/16))
largefont=pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",int(display_width/10))
gamedisplay.fill(green)
block=display_height/12
pygame.display.update()
def quit_game():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            quit()
def intro_screen():
    welcome_message = mediumfont.render(str("Welcome to Stacker!!!"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(welcome_message,(display_width/4,display_height/40))
    how_to_play_1=smallfont.render(str("Your goal is to get to the major prize bar"),True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(how_to_play_1,(display_width/3.619909502,display_height/2))
    how_to_play=smallfont.render(str("Press the space bar to stop the shape"),True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(how_to_play,(display_width/3.48583878,display_height/(12/7)))
    quit_game()
    pygame.display.update()
def middle_block():
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue,(display_width/(32/15),display_height-block,block,block))
    pygame.display.update()
def left_block():
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue,(display_width/(32/13),display_height-block,block,block))
    pygame.display.update()
def right_block():
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue,(display_width/(32/17),display_height-block,block,block))
    pygame.display.update()
def major_screen():
    major_message = mediumfont.render(str("Major Prize Here!"), True,black)
    gamedisplay.blit(major_message,(display_width/(10/3),display_height/40))
    pygame.display.update()
intro_screen()
pygame.time.delay(8000)
gamedisplay.fill(green)
major_screen()
pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue,(display_width-display_width,display_height/8,display_width,display_height/60))
pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, blue,(display_width-display_width,display_height/2.4,display_width,display_height/60))
middle_block()
left_block()
right_block()
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no **main** game-loop. You may thinks this:

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            quit()
```

Is your game-loop. While that is almost correct, it is missing a key part. A **while** loop. Your telling Python to loop through every single event that Pygame is tracking. After it finishes looping through the events **once**, it stops. You want Python to **continually** loop through the Pygame events, until the window is closed. To do this create a variable to control your loop. Such as `running = True` or `not_quit = True`. Next wrap a while-loop around your for-loop using the control variable as your condition. Lastly, if the user closes the window, set your control variable to `False`.

```
running = True # our variable to control the loop.
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False # break the loop
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            quit()
```

This should allow you to close your window. I should note however that none of the text/shapes your blitting/drawing to the screen will be visible unless inside your game-loop. So you may need to rethink your code a bit.

Comment: Ok, thanks, your answer worked just fine. I took out sys.exit() command so the system ask the user are you sure you want to quit. But overall works fine. Thank you. And I was going to put a  main loop in there. In fact it has one now. Thanks.